# How to convert array to multidimensional array with special keys using php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array

```
$array = [
    0=>1 
    1=>Jon 
    2=>jon@email.com 
    3=>2 
    4=>Doe 
    5=>doe@email.com 
    6=>3
    7=>Foo 
    8=>foo@email.com
]
```

What I`d like to do is to add and extra value to each value.
Something like this so I can access it when looping through the array

```
$array=[
    0=>1[id] 
    1=>Jon[name] 
    2=>jon@email.com[email] 
    3=>2[id] 
    4=>Doe[name] 
    5=>doe@email.com[email] 
    6=>3[id] 
    7=>Foo[name] 
    8=>foo@email.com[email]
]
```

I guess it would be a multidimensional array?
What would be the proper way of doing it?

Comment: The proper way of doing it would be this way:
`$array = [
    [
        'id'=>1,
        'name'=>Jon,
        'email'=>jon@email.com
    ],
    [
        'id'=>2,
        'name'=>Doe,
        'email'=>doe@email.com
    ],
    [
        'id'=>3,
        'name'=>Foo,
        'email'=>foo@email.com
    ]
];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through array and check key of items and based of it create new array and insert values in it.

```
$newArr = [];    
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    if ($key % 3 == 0)
        $newArr[] = ["id" => $value];
    if ($key % 3 == 1)
        $newArr[sizeof($newArr)-1]["name"] = $value;
    if ($key % 3 == 2)
        $newArr[sizeof($newArr)-1]["email"] = $value;
}
```

Check result in [demo](https://ideone.com/Z4DGYf)

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answers the OP's question

Comment: One question though. How can I access "string" or "int"?

Comment: @Davis If you mean getting int or string value from array, you should use `$array[index]` to get value. for example `$array[1]` and type of value not important

Answer (score 0):

yes just use 2 dimension array

```
$arr = array();

$arr[0][0] = "1"
$arr[0][1] = "Jon"
$arr[0][2] = "jon@email.com"

$arr[1][0] = "2"
$arr[1][1] = "Doe"
$arr[1][2] = "doe@email.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since an array is a map in PHP, I'd recommend to use it like a map or to create a class holding the data.

```
$arr = array();
$arr[0]['ID'] = 1;
$arr[0]['name'] = "John";
$arr[0]['mail'] = "john@email.com;
```

Example for one class:

```
 <?PHP
 class User
    {
        public $id;
        public $name;
        public $mail;

        function __construct($ID,$name,$mail)
        {
            $this->id = $ID;
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->mail = $mail;
        }
    }
?>
```

and then you can simply use it like that:

```
 <?PHP
    require_once("User.php");
    $user = new User(1,"Mario","maio290@foo.bar");
    echo $user->name;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this:

```
$array1 = ["name"=>"alaex","class"=>4];
$array2 = ["name"=>"aley","class"=>10];
$array3 = ["student"=>$array1,"student2"=>$array2];

print_r($array3);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple, yet often-used solution is to use multidimensional array with string keys for better readability:

```
$array = [
    0 => [
        'id'    => 1,
        'name'  => 'Jon',
        'email' => 'jon@email.com',
    ],
    1 => [
        'id'    => 2,
        'name'  => 'Doe',
        'email' => 'doe@email.com',
    ],
    2 => [
        'id'    => 3,
        'name'  => 'Foo',
        'email' => 'foo@email.com',
    ],
];
```

You can loop through this like so:

```
for ($array as $item) {
    // $item['id']
    // $item['name']
    // $item['email']
}
```

---

But since PHP is an object-oriented language, I'd suggest creating a class for the data-structure. This is even easier to read and you can very easily add functionality related to the entity etc.

```
class Person {
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $email;

    function __construct($id, $name, $email) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->email = $email;
    }
}

$array = [
    0 => new Person(1, 'Jon', 'jon@email.com'),
    1 => new Person(2, 'Doe', 'doe@email.com'),
    2 => new Person(3, 'Foo', 'foo@email.com'),
];
```

You can loop through this like so:

```
for ($array as $person) {
    // $person->id
    // $person->name
    // $person->email
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_map` on the result of `array_chunck` this way:

```
 $array=array_map(function($val){ return array_combine(['id','name','email'],$val);}, array_chunk($array,3));
```

note that the second parameter of `array_chunk` depend of the number of columns and the first array used in `array_combine` too

see the [working code here](https://3v4l.org/Z4sMR)

Comment: @IcedAnt now  there is one more answer to solve the question

Comment: One question though. How can I access "string" or ''int"?

Comment: you don't need to access string or int.it just a dump.You can use $array[0]['id'] or any column else using normal array brackets access

Comment: @Davis take a look again to https://3v4l.org/Y3ND2 the full working example....the answer marked as the solution can't easily handle columns up to ten without many lines of complex calcul and code.Mine can.

Comment: Well the trick is that my code has to check whether data is string or int or date so I actually need to access it. That was the idea behind putting an extra value to value

Comment: @Davis do the actual marked answer solved this requirement yet? why don't you then edit your question to make it  more clear by for example adding your expected output.That would be very usefull for everybody

Comment: Yes I actually didn`t ask the correct question. 
My question as I stated it has been answered.
Thanks for help everyone!